# How to read xml files in a specific directory using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to use WinSCP .NET assembly to loop for xml files with a specific condition in a directory I'll be thankful for any help.

I used the below logic to iterate through xml files in the ErrorMessages directory for the solution in my system ( providing local path), want to use the same logic using WinSCP .NET assembly:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:/GIS/Production/ErrorMessages");

for (int i = 0; i < files.ToList().Count - 1; i++)
{
    var fileName = files.ToList()[i].Replace(@"\", "/");

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);

    XmlNodeList customerList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Document/Body");
    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("InvoiceResponse/Subscribers");

    for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < customerList.Count; j++)
    {
        tw.WriteLine(customerList[j].InnerXml + "," + nodeList[k].InnerXml);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see the below linkhttps://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_interpreting_xml_log